# Remove specific objects from a list

Tags: c#

I have a class that has an `list<Book>` in it, and those `Book` objects has many many properties.
How can I remove from that list every Book that his `level` value is different than, for example, 5?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In this particular case, [`List<T>.RemoveAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx) is probably your friend:

C# 3:

```
list.RemoveAll(x => x.level != 5);
```

C# 2:

```
list.RemoveAll(delegate(Book x) { return x.level != 5; });
```

Comment: can we do list.Remove(x => x.level ==5);? If we want to remove a book whose level is 5.

Comment: @FarazAhmad: You can use `list.RemoveAll(x => x.level == 5)`. There's no overload of `Remove` which takes a predicate though.

Answer (score 5):

`list.RemoveAll(bk => bk.Level != 5);`

Answer (score 1):

```
list.RemoveAll(delegate(Book b) { return b.Level == 5; });
```

Answer (score 1):

Although List.RemoveAll() is an excellent solution, it does a "foreach" on the collection resuling in O(n) or worse performance. If you have lots of items in the list, i would suggest checking out Erick's Index 4 Objects collections.

See  http://www.codeplex.com/i4o